# Error in making custom application part of android Operating System

Tags: android

I am trying to make my application part of android OS, i downloaded the [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) (CM7) and compiled it successfully, i am following instructions from [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_H4AlQaNa0):

The name of the application is "HitMe".

Here are the steps which i followed:

1. cd Cyanogen/packages/apps
2. ln -s /home/usama/Desktop/HitMe
3. cd HitMe
4. Copy the Android.mk file , this is the Android.mk file
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
   include $((CLEAR_VARS)

   ## Build all java files in the java subdirectory (there is # in the start, its a comment)

   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all -subdir -java-files)

   ## Name of the APK to build (there is # in the start, its a comment)

   LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := HitMe

   include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
5. rm -rf bin gen
6. cd Cyanogen/Build/target/product
7. add "HitMe /" in the core.mk file
8. cd Cyanogen/packages/apps/HitMe
9. mm
   And i got this error:

   usama@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Cyanogen/packages/apps$ cd HitMe

   usama@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Cyanogen/packages/apps/HitMe$ mm

   ============================================

   PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL

   PLATFORM_VERSION=2.3.7

   TARGET_PRODUCT=full

   TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng

   TARGET_SIMULATOR=

   TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release

   TARGET_BUILD_APPS=

   TARGET_ARCH=arm

   TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a

   HOST_ARCH=x86

   HOST_OS=linux

   HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release

   BUILD_ID=GINGERBREAD

   ============================================

   make: Entering directory `/home/usama/Desktop/Cyanogen'
     make: *** No rule to make target`out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-      res_intermediates/src/R.stamp', needed by `out/target/common/obj/APPS/LocalPackage_intermediates/src/R.stamp'.  Stop.

I thought this would only be happening with my application, but i tried this with DSPManager(which came as a service in CM-7) and i got the exact same error, here is the output of terminal

```
  usama@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Cyanogen/packages/apps/DSPManager$ mm
  ============================================
  PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
  PLATFORM_VERSION=2.3.7
  TARGET_PRODUCT=full
  TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
  TARGET_SIMULATOR=
  TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
  TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
  TARGET_ARCH=arm
  TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
  HOST_ARCH=x86
  HOST_OS=linux
  HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
  BUILD_ID=GINGERBREAD
  ============================================
  make: Entering directory `/home/usama/Desktop/Cyanogen'
  make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-      res_intermediates/src/R.stamp', needed by `out/target/common/obj/APPS/DSPManager_intermediates/src/R.stamp'.  Stop.
```

make: Leaving directory `/home/usama/Desktop/Cyanogen'
usama@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Cyanogen/packages/apps/DSPManager$

Any idea, about how this can be resolved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `m` (I guess) or `make` is required before you can build subpackages.

It complains that there is no `out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework` (that's the core android framework) which you don't have unless you do a complete build first.

You can then build parts of the whole project

```
~/Desktop/Cyanogen$ m
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem can be the following: you do not clean your Hitme project. After you make an applciation in Eclipse you should turn off build automatically and make clean this Hitme project. After this you can go to root folder run `mmm packages/apps/HitMe snod` or run the whole make if you have errors.